# Inserting arabic strings into database in grails

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have a grails application which sends short messages to mobile phone. Before sending, it saves the messages in database. All goes well when the messages are in english but when I type arabic in the fields and insert it into database then it comes in some question mark form. like this ???????. what should I do with this. I want to insert arabic characters into database.

Comment: What database you use? Best would be to put it into question text and title

Comment: I use sqlserver as a database.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a database issue. As lukelazarovic mentioned, you need to provide the type of database you use. If you are using MySQL then you need to set the Collation to utf8. I use `utf8_general_ci` for Arabic. Also if you are showing the messages in an web page then make sure you have the proper content type in the header, for example `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`.